Reasons for the discrepancies in the names listed in 2 Samuel 23:24-39
In examining two different versions there is a difference in the list of names given. The NASB and several other translations (ESV, KJV, NKJV) list two differences opposed to the NIV:

Jonathan and Shammah the Hararite appear to be listed as two separate people.
Bani the Gadite is listed.

2 Samuel 23:24-39 NASB

24 Asahel the brother of Joab was among the thirty; and there was
Elhanan the son of Dodo of Bethlehem, 25 Shammah the Harodite, Elika
the Harodite, 26 Helez the Paltite, Ira the son of Ikkesh the Tekoite,
27 Abiezer the Anathothite, Mebunnai the Hushathite, 28 Zalmon the
Ahohite, Maharai the Netophathite, 29 Heleb the son of Baanah the
Netophathite, Ittai the son of Ribai of Gibeah of the sons of
Benjamin, 30 Benaiah a Pirathonite, Hiddai of the brooks of Gaash, 31
Abi-albon the Arbathite, Azmaveth the Barhumite, 32 Eliahba the
Shaalbonite, the sons of Jashen, Jonathan, 33 Shammah the Hararite,
Ahiam the son of Sharar the Ararite, 34 Eliphelet the son of Ahasbai,
the son of the Maacathite, Eliam the son of Ahithophel the Gilonite,
35 Hezro the Carmelite, Paarai the Arbite, 36 Igal the son of Nathan
of Zobah, Bani the Gadite, 37 Zelek the Ammonite, Naharai the
Beerothite, armor bearers of Joab the son of Zeruiah, 38 Ira the
Ithrite, Gareb the Ithrite, 39 and Uriah the Hittite; thirty-seven in
all.

The NIV on the other hand:

Jonathan appears as the son of Shammah the Hararite.
Bani the Gadite is omitted entirely.

2 Samuel 23:24-39 NIV

24 Among the Thirty were: Asahel the brother of Joab,
Elhanan son of Dodo from Bethlehem,
25 Shammah the Harodite,
Elika the Harodite,
26 Helez the Paltite,
Ira son of Ikkesh from Tekoa,
27 Abiezer from Anathoth,
Sibbekai the Hushathite,
28 Zalmon the Ahohite,
Maharai the Netophathite,
29 Heled son of Baanah the Netophathite,
Ithai son of Ribai from Gibeah in Benjamin,
30 Benaiah the Pirathonite,
Hiddai from the ravines of Gaash,
31 Abi-Albon the Arbathite,
Azmaveth the Barhumite,
32 Eliahba the Shaalbonite,
the sons of Jashen,
Jonathan 33 son of Shammah the Hararite,
Ahiam son of Sharar the Hararite,
34 Eliphelet son of Ahasbai the Maakathite,
Eliam son of Ahithophel the Gilonite,
35 Hezro the Carmelite,
Paarai the Arbite,
36 Igal son of Nathan from Zobah,
the son of Hagri,
37 Zelek the Ammonite,
Naharai the Beerothite, the armor-bearer of Joab son of Zeruiah,
38 Ira the Ithrite,
Gareb the Ithrite
39 and Uriah the Hittite.
There were thirty-seven in all.

Are there any known textual variants or manuscript differences that account for the discrepancies?
What is the reason for the difference in the translations?
